# How to set environment variables for ANT build.xml file? (Java)

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I am trying to open a project with the Windows version of Eclipse, but after choosing to open the build.xml file the error message says:

> Problem setting the classpath of the
>   project from the javac classpath:
>   C:\project1\${env.TOMCATEB_HOME}

I tried to set TOMCATEB_HOME environment variable in the Windows control panel, pointing to the Tomcat root folder (the one that has uninstall.exe), but it had no effect.